# populating ui-grid with asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-grid

This is how my piece of code looks like -

```
   var frameworkModule = angular.module('frameworkModule',
      ['ngRoute', 'ngGrid']); 

   frameworkModule.controller('homeController', 
        ['$scope', 'valuesService', '$http', 
        function ($scope, valuesService, $http) {

    getData1();
    getData2();

    function getData1() {
        $scope.myData1 = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                         { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                         { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                         { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                         { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];
        $scope.gridOptions1 = { data: 'myData1' };
    }

    function getData2() {
        $http.get('/api/values').success(function (gridData) {
            $scope.myData2 = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                         { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                         { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                         { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                         { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];
            $scope.gridOptions2 = { data: 'myData2' };
        });
    }
}]);
```

Please note that the `frameworkModule` and `homeController` directives are specified correctly in my html.
This is how my grid html looks like-

```
<div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions1">
<div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions2">
```

Now my issue is that the data in `gridOptions1` is displaying as expected, but the data in  `gridOptions2` does not display at all.

The piece of code in `$http` call is just a sample to show what i intend to do. Once my `gridOptions2` grid is working i will show data that is returned from `/api/values` call in `gridData`parameter. Also note that my web api `/api/values` is called correctly and it returns the json data for grid as expected.

Can anybody please help me understand what is the difference between `getData1` and `getData2` and why my code in `getData2` does not work as expected?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your console to make sure your network request is working as intended?

Comment: Could you try adding the .error() function after success() to see if that is hit and what it contains? Syntax at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http (I am not clear on whether you're saying the api call is working directly in a browser or whether you're actually entering the success() function...)

Comment: @S.Baggy - i have the error() function after $http call and it does not get hit. When i say "api call is working", i mean the success() function is getting hit. The network request is working fine. Please advice if you find anything suspicious.